# Any guidelines as to what's a sufficient level of "being succinct" research papers?

Tags: publications

Any guidelines as to what's a sufficient level of "being succinct" research papers?

This confuses me, because it seems to me like "being succinct" is sold as an *ideal* ("a very desirable thing to have"). But when trying to figure out "well how to produce succinct text", then I find as if there are no general guidelines for it and that it could well be "very subjective" thing.

Based on subjective experience on reading "experienced papers" I would also argue that "being succinct" may come at the cost of not having said information that would have been necessary. I.e. leaving out important information at the cost of appearing "nicer in text".

Comment: Faulkner and Joyce are not succinct. Hemingway is.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a guideline: Follow the six rules near the end of this essay by George Orwell
https://www.orwellfoundation.com/the-orwell-foundation/orwell/essays-and-other-works/politics-and-the-english-language/

especially

- Never use a long word where a short one will do.
- If it is possible to cut a word [or phrase] out, always cut it out.

In your question, you could cut the start of the 2nd paragraph up to "like" and the last sentence of the 3rd paragraph. I know it is not supposed to be academic writing, but it is just an example of how to be succinct.

But you are right that it is subjective. It depends on the field as well.

Comment: This essay is fabulous. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While it is notoriously hard to figure out what to cover and what to omit, there is a handful of purely linguistic tricks. toby544 provided a good example of those, and there are plenty more to be found (another set of key words you might find useful: informative writing).

I will focus on something else instead. The mindset.
The mind in turmoil struggles to communicate thoughts clearly. I find confidence and clarity absolutely essential for writing. There is no need to omit the thought process entirely while sticking to the subject matter like you suggest in the comments.

Text becomes hard to read because of not-so-necessary fluff: overuse of passive voice, waltzing around conclusions with "probably" and "might indicate", dealing almost exclusively in hypotheticals. These are also the hallmarks of a large part of academic writing: dropping careful formulations is also no good, after all. So how to find that balance, then?

By grouping all the "maybe, maybe not" and "this is not conclusive" bits together. Do not let your - and your reader's - mind wander around too much during a single explanation. You might stop at some key concepts and briefly address possible concerns if it doesn't require going too much in-depth. If it does, find a simpler explanation.

Finally, it is impossible to cover everything required to understand the subject in a single body of text. Spend a lot of time considering the scope: who is your audience? What do and don't they know?
This is a lot of work, and the answers can't be given in general. Some examples of questions can.

Answer (score 0):

Being succint is not subjective. Being succint is actually the most objective way to write something because you need to focus on what your audience **knows** and **doesn't know**.

A short example: if you are demonstrating a theorem and you perform an addition, you need to specify that the operation is commutative to K12 students, probably not to graduate in mathemathics.

That's why there are great papers, interesting papers, boring papers: some papers flow with you and your knowledge, some rely on your knowledge to miss the gaps, some get you annoyed spending long time in *obvious* things.

Given the variety of the background and of the knowledge of the readership, professionals in a given field will not unanimously agree on which one is a great paper, but it is quite likely that if 50%-60% of the specialists think a paper is a great paper, then the paper is deemed to be a great paper, even if 20% of the readers maybe think "there are too many missing information in this paper".

Comment: Yes I initially thought that in order to minimize subjective preferences one ought to imprint as little one's own subjective taste as possible. But OTOH after viewing text in such style I found that "being succinct" carries the problem of being "**too plain to be replicable**". I.e. **by reducing information one also loses tacit knowledge etc.** which may **make it very difficult to interpret "what was this person thinking, when he/she writes this"**. Thus **the *process* may become buried, while the information gained (or "the result") is there**.

Comment: I don't know if knowing what the audience knows and doesn't know is very easy, unless one knows the readers very well. Which might only be possible in some very small field? But if you don't know, what the "use cases" for your readers will be, then it sounds like throwing a dice. I.e. that it's very, very complicated to know what to put there and what to leave out.

Comment: @mavavilj Precisely. This is why writing well is so hard.

Comment: "Being succint is actually the most objective way to write something because you need to focus on what your audience knows and doesn't know." That doesn't follow.

Comment: @toby544 succint, not concise

Comment: @EarlGrey  I don't know what you mean. I think you are using "succinct" and "objective" with different meanings from what most people mean by those words.

Comment: @toby544 https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/succinct *expressed clearly and in a few words* vs 
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/concise *giving only the information that is necessary and important, using few words*
Synonyms? yes, maybe. same thing? not at all.

Comment: @toby544 to conclude: succint means expressing clearly. Expressing clearly *to whom*? to your audience. Therefore the objectivity of being succint follows, however you need to know your audience, to know what they will consider clear and they will need to have explained.

Comment: "Synonyms? yes, maybe. same thing? not at all." I don't think it is possible for two words to be "maybe" synonyms but "not at all" mean the same thing. Your argument that succinct writing is objective is not clear at all. And it is "succinct", not "succint."

Comment: @toby544 Big and large are synonyms. They do not mean the same thing. Unless you consider succinct and concise meaning the same thing, of course.

Comment: @EarlGrey What do you mean they don’t mean the same? They are semantically equivalent!!

Comment: @user354948 Please. Just look at their ethimology, one comes from tightening up (succint), the other from cutting out (concise). 
They are synonyms, which does not mean they have the same meaning.

Comment: @EarlGrey Etymology is not meaning. And “Ethimology” isn’t a word in English. Synonyms are words with the same meaning, by definition. I have never seen you so wrong in what you are saying.

Comment: @user354948 *one of two or more words or expressions of the same language that have the same or nearly the same meaning in some or all senses*
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym

You are welcome to say that 3.14 and pi have nearly the same value, you will be correct 99% of the time. But please note that  1% of the times you will be very wrong

Comment: @user354948 additionally, have a look at the rules from the most voted answer
https://www.orwellfoundation.com/the-orwell-foundation/orwell/essays-and-other-works/politics-and-the-english-language/ rule i-ii-iv are succinct, rule iii is concise . Enjoy!

Comment: @EarlGrey This is just the result of concept creep: you are using an expanded definition of “synonym” that doesn’t requiere semantic overlapping to be total. Obviously if you do that synonyms don’t have to mean exactly the same thing. I have no beef regarding the difference between succinctness and conciseness, so I won’t look at those rules. I’d still like to know what semantic difference you see between “big” and “large”. Are you referring to expressions such as “He’s big on Star Wars” or something like that?

Comment: @user354948 something not like that.

Comment: @EarlGrey That’s as vague as possible; so you don’t have an explanation?

Comment: @EarlGrey Didn’t get the Pi example either. Isn’t Pi defined as that value? You’re being a little cryptic here.