Writing a Book Chapter and Adjusting One's Scholarly Tone (Writing Style)
I'm turning my master's dissertation into a book chapter and I'm worried about my scholarly tone. When I read other articles they don't sound like the way I have written my dissertation and I'll be using a lot of it in my article. Is there a specific way to write my article? I've been searching a lot about this and watching videos on Youtube, but I can't find any practical advice other than normal tips such as avoiding generlaisations, unnecessary jargon, etc.
To sum up, is this normal or is there a way to make my writing sound more like what we usually read in journal articles?

If all articles you read sound greatly different from your style, then it does seem likely that your style is not very scholarly. But it is hard for us to say anything when we don't know how your style is different. Maybe you could put an example of your writing here. Also see other questions on this site, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/178065/

I'm a bit confused now because in another posted question you indicate that you want to turn your dissertation into a journal article. Which is it---book chapter or journal article?

What contribution is being made by your dissertation advisor to edit your writing style?

Hello Eggy, it's a book chapter. It was a misunderstanding on my part sorry.

Thanks Toby for the link. Will check it out.

Hello Jeffrey, I haven't been able to reach my dissertation advisor. I contacted her a while back just to say hi but haven't gotten a response, so felt quite reluctant to send her an email asking for help. That's also why I'm scouring the internet trying to look for advice on how to write it.
As a matter of fact, the feedback I got from the examination board at my uni said that my dissertation was professionally written, well-argued, and very engaging to read. While I was taking out parts from it, I just felt it would be very different from how articles are written. That's why I was asking.

Are you referring to a multi-author edited book? If so, the book's editor should have given you instructions for writing your chapter, including clarification of the book's audience and the desired content and stye. All the chapters in the book don't have to sound the same, since they're written by different authors, but it's also probably true that one chapter shouldn't stand out as radically different from all the others.
You ask, "Is there a way to make my writing sound more like what we usually read in journal articles?" But you say you're writing a book chapter, not a journal article. A book may have a broader audience than a journal, but it's hard to say that without knowing the topic of the book and of your chapter. Perhaps you'd like to say what that is?
Are you sure that "what we usually read in journal articles" is good writing? How do you recognize good writing? All good writing is clear, whether scholarly or not. I'm not sure that what we usually read in journal articles is something to emulate. As an academic editor, I know I've hit my target when a book reviewer says, "I recommend publishing this book because the style is simple, clear, and not weighed down by jargon that leaves readers scratching their heads."
Finally, if you were invited to write a book chapter based on the editor having read your dissertation, that indicates that the editor has faith in you, so have faith in yourself. Give it your best shot and ask the editor to give you feedback for making improvements.
I'd be happy to help you offline, but I don't think StackExchange has any mechanism for connecting users.

but I don't think StackExchange has any mechanism for connecting users. You can go to chat where the discussion is less public (though still visible to anyone who bothers to visit the chat room) to start with.

@fedja I would gladly help the OP directly by reviewing the chapter. That would require an exchange of email addresses that could compromise privacy.

If you don't care much about your privacy (judging from what you've said about yourself, you are a semi-public figure already :-) ), you can leave your e-mail address and wait for the OP to contact you. Otherwise, yeah, there is a problem...

Yeah . . . in fact I do care about my privacy and want to respect the poster's privacy.
